# Vim: what are all the possible swapfile extensions?

Tags: vim, filenames

When you're editing a file in vim, it generates a swapfile with the same name as your current file, but with a `.swp` extension.

If `.swp` is already taken, then it generates one a `.swo` one. If that's already taken, then you get `.swa`, etc. etc.

I couldn't find any documentation on what the exact naming-fallback order is for these files, can anyone clarify by what convention the extensions are chosen?

Comment: See also: [vim.se]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**tl;dr** `swp`, `swo`, ..., `swa`, `svz`, `svy`, ..., `sva`, ..., `saa`. Upon reaching the last one it triggers an error.

The particular piece of code that you're looking for (and comment) is in [`memline.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v9.0.1682/src/memline.c#L5272-L5289):

```
    /* 
     * Change the ".swp" extension to find another file that can be used. 
     * First decrement the last char: ".swo", ".swn", etc. 
     * If that still isn't enough decrement the last but one char: ".svz" 
     * Can happen when editing many "No Name" buffers. 
     */
    if (fname[n - 1] == 'a')        /* ".s?a" */
    {   
        if (fname[n - 2] == 'a')    /* ".saa": tried enough, give up */
        {   
            EMSG(_("E326: Too many swap files found"));
            vim_free(fname);
            fname = NULL;
            break;  
        }
        --fname[n - 2];             /* ".svz", ".suz", etc. */
        fname[n - 1] = 'z' + 1;
    }
    --fname[n - 1];                 /* ".swo", ".swn", etc. */
```

Answer (score 24):

The information from the code snippet *is* in Vim's help. See [`:h swap-file`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#swap-file):

```
The name of the swap file is normally the same as the file you are editing,
with the extension ".swp".
- On Unix, a '.' is prepended to swap file names in the same directory as the
  edited file.  This avoids that the swap file shows up in a directory
  listing.
- On MS-DOS machines and when the 'shortname' option is on, any '.' in the
  original file name is replaced with '_'.
- If this file already exists (e.g., when you are recovering from a crash) a
  warning is given and another extension is used, ".swo", ".swn", etc.
- An existing file will never be overwritten.
- The swap file is deleted as soon as Vim stops editing the file.

Technical: The replacement of '.' with '_' is done to avoid problems with
       MS-DOS compatible filesystems (e.g., crossdos, multidos).  If Vim
       is able to detect that the file is on an MS-DOS-like filesystem, a
       flag is set that has the same effect as the 'shortname' option.
       This flag is reset when you start editing another file.

                            *E326*
       If the ".swp" file name already exists, the last character is
       decremented until there is no file with that name or ".saa" is
       reached.  In the last case, no swap file is created.
```

Comment: Unfortunately the description in the docs is ambiguous.

Answer (score 21):

In, slightly easier on the eyes, regex-speak:

```
[._]*.s[a-v][a-z]
[._]*.sw[a-p]
[._]s[a-v][a-z]
[._]sw[a-p]
```

The source for this is Github's own gitignore file for [Vim](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Vim.gitignore).

Comment: This seems to incorrectly match ".swq" through ".swz".

Comment: @EricTowers It should be correct now.

Comment: Perhaps more important...  Have you pushed at patch at git?  :-)

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2208 :-)

Answer (score 17):

### good enough `.gitignore`

While the other answers here are clearly more technically complete here is a **good enough** entry for most `.gitignore`s which is where I've cared about this most often:

```
# vim swap files
##################
*.sw[a-p]
```

As you can see from the other answers `vim` can create hundreds of other names, but you'd have to stack up **16** swap files before this would fail.  By generalizing to something like `*.s[a-z][a-z]` could appear more correct it will also match [lots of valid extensions](https://www.file-extensions.org/search/?searchstring=s&searchtype=2) which in the case of `.gitignore` means those files won't be tracked by `git`.  I've never managed to create 16 swap files for the same file in 20 years of using `vim` so I hope you can manage to do the same and this will work for you.

### stricter version

As pointed out in the comments Flash developers may have `.swf` files so you may prefer

```
*.sw[g-p]
```

which will still ignore 10 swap files which is plenty for most people.  The only sad part is you lose the "swap" mnemonic.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that's only going to catch "swp" since the next one is "swo" not "swq". Personally, I use "*.sw[a-p]" for the reason you gave and also because it reads "swap" :)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for catching that.  I've corrected my answer.  Now to fix my git repos.  (But this goes to show how few extra swap files I create!)

Comment: Eh, why so complex? `*.sw?`

Comment: To avoid ignoring  things that aren't vim swap files like `.sw2` or `.sw$` that should be tracked in the repo.

Comment: Remember to include your `.swf` files. Or upgrade your Flash developers to HTML5 :-)

Comment: I'm tempted by `.sw[g-p]` but that messes up the "readability".  Mercifully I avoided Flash except as an enduser.

Comment: You can avoid most legitimate files being caught by checking for the leading `.` or `_` which is also added.

Comment: I discovered the `*.sw[a-p]` mnemonic myself. I love it :)

Comment: Swap files are (always?) hidden files, and one tipically doesn't want to track those, so you can do `.sw[a-p]\n.*.sw[a-p]` (that \n should be a newline). It repeats, but it's readable and now your not-hidden flash files will not be ignored. EDIT: added missing dot to extension.

Comment: I think the flash version should be obsolete as flash isn't supported anymore

Comment: @WayneWerner This is awesome. It's easy to remember and I doubt I'll ever need more than 16 swap files. I haven't even reached `.swn` yet.

Answer (score 5):

This .gitignore alternative should satisfy everyone. The second line negates ignoring '*.swf'.

```
*.sw[a-p]
!*.swf
```